# textContent on created element in JS not working?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on a school task, but I recently got stuck with a textContent issue. I import a JSON file and use the data as a foreach. There are no errors in the .js file, but i receive a typeError: cannot set property 'textContent' of undefined, even though i defined the properties with elements from the JSON file?

When I remove the two lines with textContent, I receive a similar error with the appendChild property: cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

If i log coffee.name in my forEach, I do get the correct first name. I'm guessing i only get one name since the forEach can't loop further because of the errors further along.

My js code:

```
    import './style.css';
    import data from './assets/data/coffees.json';

  const init = () => {
 console.log(data);
 createPriceList(data);
};

const createPriceList = coffees => {
const ul = document.querySelector('prices__list');
console.log(coffees);

coffees.coffees.forEach(coffee => {
 if (coffee.plantbased === true) {
  const price = document.createElement('li');
  price.classList.add('price');
  const a = document.createElement('a').classList.add('price__button');
  const spanWrapper = document.createElement('span').classList.add('price__button__wrapper');
  const spanName = document.createElement('span').classList.add('price__button__name');
  const spanAmount = document.createElement('span').classList.add('price__button__amount');
  const spanPlus = document.createElement('span').classList.add('price__button__plus');

  spanName.textContent = coffee.name;
  spanAmount.textContent = coffee.prices.medium;

  ul.appendChild(price);
  price.appendChild(a);
  a.appendChild(spanWrapper);
  spanWrapper.appendChild(spanName);
  spanWrapper.appendChild(spanAmount);
  a.appendChild(spanPlus);
  }
  });
 };

init();
```

Here is the HTML I'm trying to create (the section in comment, the rest is defined):

```
<section class="prices highlight spaced">
  <h2 class="visually-hidden">Price list</h2>
  <ul class="prices__list">
  <!--<li class="price">
        <a class="price__button">
          <span class="price__button__wrapper">
            <span class="price__button__name">Oat Latte</span>
            <span class="price__button__amount">&euro; 2</span>
          </span>
          <span class="price__button__plus">+</span>
        </a>
      </li> -->
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to chain methods together like this:

```js
const test = document.createElement('span').classList.add('price__button__name');
console.log(test.classList);
```

But, you have to create the element first and then you can work with its `classList` or other properties:

```js
const test = document.createElement('span');
test.classList.add('price__button__name');
console.log(test.classList);
```

Comment: Thanks, I changed it, but now I receive the appendChild error again: cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

Comment: @ArthurRobaeys Have you corrected ***all*** the `document.createElement` lines?

Comment: Yes I have, all those in the forEach.

Comment: Which exact line is failing (`ul.appendChild()` or `a.appendChild()`)?

Comment: Dev tools tells me it's the first one: ul.appendChild(price);

Comment: I Changed it, but it doesn't seem to be the fix; still the same error. I always use that arrow function though, don't really understand what u are suggesting. I pass data in my init function along with createPriceList, and then I 'rename' data to a more readable parameter 'coffees'.

Comment: @ScottMarcus You absolutely CAN assign an arrow function to a variable, and you CAN pass them anywhere that expects a function. Arrow functions are functions in every way, except for how they bind the value of `this`; anything that expects a function will work fine with arrow functions as well.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk Ignore last comment.

Comment: Your error means that `const ul = document.querySelector('prices__list');` is not finding a DOM element, double check that `ul` is not null.

Comment: It's probably important to note that `document.querySelector('prices__list')` will be looking for an element with a *tag name* of `prices__list`; if you want to find an ID, you either prepend that with a `#` or use `document.getElementById` instead.

Comment: Just checked, the name is correct. I added my HTML code in case you wanted to see it.

Comment: You are looking for an element by class, so the code should be: `const ul = document.querySelector('.prices__list');` (with a dot in front of the class name).

Comment: Oh my god, I can't believe it was the fricking dot. Thanks a lot!